# error while loading shared libraries: cv2.so

Tags: linux, opencv

I build a program, that uses OpenCV-2.4.0 libraries, using CodeBlocks on Debian 7.0.0.

When I try to run the resulting executable I get the message

```
error while loading shared libraries: cv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

cv2.so is found in /usr/local/lib and when I type

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I get

```
/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: What does `ldd your-program` tell you about cv2.so?

Comment: And you're saying that $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is `/usr/local/lib` and therein lies `cv2.so`?  If so, something doesn't add up.  Can you `ls -l $LD_LIBRARY_PATH/cv2.so` and tell us what's there?

Comment: I found the problem.  I had run ". .bashrc" in one terminal window and then tried to run the program in another.  Thanks, Peter.